# Listening for a cookie sent from php page

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I have a page with the following:

```
<script>
    window.setInterval(function () {
        var cookie = $.cookie('download');
            if (cookie !== null) {
                console.log(cookie);
            }
    }, 500); 
</script>
```

It is checking a `cookie` called **download** and its value of 0 (previously set) is being displayed in the console.

From this page I can click a button which launches a php pdf generating file and just before the pdf is output (to download the pdf) have:

```
<?php 
    ... pdf created ...
    setcookie("download", 1);
    output pdf;
?>
```

suposedly to mark set the `cookie` as 1 to indicate the download is complete. However this change is not reflected in the console and the `cookie` remains with the value 0.

Is what I am trying to do possible? And if so what am I doing wrong?

This method is proposed with this question: [Is there any event/way we can know when a file has finished downloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35596333/is-there-any-event-way-we-can-know-when-a-file-has-finished-downloading)

Comment: And mark down by all means but please say why.

Comment: Cookies are sent in response header. Even tho I'm not sure what are you trying to accomplish, you can't expect that cookie will simply appear like that.

Comment: I am trying to acheive a way of knowing when a pdf file generated by php has downloaded. It is asked a great deal and I have included the link of a method. So I need to find out how to read the header in the output - is that what you are saying?

Comment: The cookie is there - it is displaying 0 - what I want to do is to change it to 1 when the pdf has completed downloading.